# parallel execution of kernels in cuda

Tags: cuda, parallel-processing, nvidia

lets say i have three global array which have been copied into gpu using cudaMemcpy but these gloabl array in c has NOT been allocated using cudaHostAlloc so as to allocate memory that is page-locked instead they are simple gloabl allocation.

```
int a[100],b [100],c[100];
cudaMemcpy(d_a,a,100*sizeof(int),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
cudaMemcpy(d_b,b,100*sizeof(int),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
cudaMemcpy(d_c,c,100*sizeof(int),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

now i have 10 kernels which are launched in seperate streams so as to run concurrently and some of them are using global array copied in gpu.
and now these kernels are running for say 1000 iterations.
they dont have to copy anything back to host during iterations.

But the problem is that they are not executing in parallel instead they are going for serial fashion.

```
  cudaStream_t stream[3];

   for(int i=0;i<3;i++)cudaStreamCreate (&stream[i]);

   for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
       kernel1<<<blocks,threads,0,stream[0]>>>(d_a,d_b);
       kernel2<<<blocks,threads,0,strea[1]>>(d_b,d_c);
      kernal3<<<blocks,threads,0,stream[2]>>>(d_c,d_a);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
  }
```

I can't understand why?

Answer (score 10):

Kernels issued this way:

```
   for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
    kernel1<<<blocks,threads>>>(d_a,d_b);
    kernel2<<<blocks,threads>>>(d_b,d_c);
    kernal3<<<blocks,threads>>>(d_c,d_a);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
  }
```

Will always run serially.  In order to get kernels to run concurrently, they must be issued to [separate CUDA streams](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#asynchronous-concurrent-execution).  And there are other requirements as well.  Read the [documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#asynchronous-concurrent-execution).

You'll need to create some CUDA streams, then launch your kernels like this:

```
   cudaStream_t stream1, stream2, stream3;
   cudaStreamCreate(&stream1); cudaStreamCreate(&stream2); cudaStreamCreate(&stream3);

   for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
    kernel1<<<blocks,threads,0,stream1>>>(d_a,d_b);
    kernel2<<<blocks,threads,0,stream2>>>(d_b,d_c);
    kernal3<<<blocks,threads,0,stream3>>>(d_c,d_a);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
  }
```

Actually witnessing concurrent kernel execution will also generally require kernels that have limited resource utilization.  If a given kernel will "fill" the machine, due to a large number of blocks, or threads per block, or shared memory usage, or some other resource usage, then you won't actually witness concurrency; there's no room left in the machine.

You may also want to review some of the CUDA sample codes, such as [simpleStreams](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#simplestreams) and [concurrentKernels](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#concurrent-kernels).

Comment: sorry for typos in the question i actally write as you have specified but it didn't work accordingly .i have made required correction in the question

Comment: The code you have shown still isn't valid.  You have `stream[i]` and `stream1`  Those will never be the same.  Anyway, you probably need to provide a complete [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  And review the documentation to discover all requirements for concurrent kernels.  Did you try running the concurrentKernels sample?

Comment: i agree with robert, your kernels must use limited ressources.

if you use cuda 7.0, maybe you can use the new per-thread default stream. http://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/gpu-pro-tip-cuda-7-streams-simplify-concurrency/